# How to use "wildcard" with a multistring query in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-4, kibana-5

I am trying to run the following query:

{"wildcard:"{"terminalId":70}} AND tranSactionResponseCode:1

The above query throws and error: Failed to parse query.......

but when I run the above query as: {"wildcard:"{"terminalId":70}} 
or when I run only the AND condition: tranSactionResponseCode:1
it runs successfully.
Please help me in figuring out how do I use both the conditions in one single query.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your `terminalId` is of type `text`.

You can try the below two queries depending on your use. First one you can only make use of the `bool` query.

```
GET mytestindex/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "wildcard": { "terminalId":   "70*"        }}, 
        { "match": { "tranSactionResponseCode": "1" }}  
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Second, from my understanding it appears that you would want to filter documents based on transaction code. In that case as well as for better query performance you can make use of the below query which is using `bool` and `filter`. Note that I have made use of `wildcard` as query context here.

```
GET mytestindex/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "wildcard": { "terminalId":   "70*" }       
        } 
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "tranSactionResponseCode": "2" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Do check the score when you execute both the queries. The second option won't take into consideration `tranSactionResponseCode` to calculate its `score`.

Hope it helps!